# Different number of cycles when running a benchmark more than once on C++ emulator

Tags: riscv

When running a benchmark e.g. dhrystone with the command:

```
make output/dhrystone.riscv.out
```

as described at: http://riscv.org/download.html#tab_rocket, 
on the C++ emulator. I get the following output: 
When running it for the first time:

```
Microseconds for one run through Dhrystone: 1064
Dhrystones per Second: 939
cycle = 533718
instret = 148672
```

and the second time:

```
Microseconds for one run through Dhrystone: 1064
Dhrystones per Second:                      939
cycle = 533715
instret = 148672
```

Why do the cycles differ? Shouldn't they be exactly the same. I have tried this with other benchmarks too and had even higher deviations. If this is normal where do the deviations come from?

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with time-of-day. Calculations on times may need different no of cycles depending on the exact values. Is that possible?

Comment: Depending on the conditions you are running, this may not be an error. Consecutive dhrystone runs aren't equivalent as the core and caches will be in subtly different states. Are those results for two different launches of the emulator or just one?

Comment: These are results for two diffrent launches of the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

There are small amounts of nondeterminism from randomly initialized registers (e.g., the clock that is recovered by the HTIF is initialized to a random phase).  It doesn't seem like these minor deviations would impact any performance benchmarking.

If you need identical results each time (e.g., for verification?), you could modify the emulator code to initialize registers to some known value each time.